# How to get a multiple value parameter using O'Reilly's multipart form servlet library?

Tags: html, servlets, parameters, multipartform-data

I'm using [O'Reilly's multipart form library for Servlets](http://www.servlets.com/cos/) to be able to process file uploading. I found it useful and realiable, but I'm facing an issue I can't solve. It's about multiple-value parameters (For example a multiple select).
I'm parsing the parameters like following:

```
List<Units> unitsParams = new ArrayList<Units>();
while (mp != null && (part = mp.readNextPart()) != null) {
    if (part.isFile()) {//Es un fichero.
        FilePart filePart = (FilePart) part;
        if (filePart.getContentType().equals("image/jpeg")) {
            InputStream pis = filePart.getInputStream();
            // It's a file, handle it
        }
    } else if (part.isParam()) { // Es un parametro
        // Handle the actual params
        String namePar = part.getName();
        ParamPart paramPart = (ParamPart) part;
        String valorPar = paramPart.getStringValue();
        boolean fin = null == valorPar;
        if (!fin) {
            if (namePar.equals("id")) {
                id = valorPar;
            } else if (namePar.equals("name")) {
                orgName = valorPar;
            } else if (namePar.equals("unitSelect")) {
                unitsParams.add(valorPar);
            }
        }
    }
```

For a multiple value parameter, I thought it would iterate (send different parts) as many times as the number of values for the param `unitSelect` I was sending, but I can get just one value.

Has anybody used this library and faced this issue? I'm trying to avoid changing the library, since the file upload is working perfectly and it's a pain to change a sigificant part of the code for few servlets.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use O'Reilly multipart/form-data parser for the reason being that [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) is more widely used and still actively maintained, and that since Servlet 3.0 you can even use built-in methods such as `getPart()` without need for any 3rd party library.

However, after checking the Javadocs and examples it seems like that you'd better use the [`MultipartRequest`](http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartRequest.html) class instead to collect the parameters. It offers `getParameter()` and `getParameterValues()` methods.

```
MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(request, saveDirectory);
File file = multipartRequest.getFile("file");
String id = multipartRequest.getParameter("id");
String name = multipartRequest.getParameter("name");
String[] unitSelect = multipartRequest.getParameterValues("unitSelect");
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)